# Cannot initialize a parameter of type CCScene COCOS2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I just use code to push scene from one scene to another.

Here is my code.

```
SettingScene *setting=[SettingScene node];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]pushScene:setting];
```

I have used same above other method that works fine but in this line it shows error...

```
/Users/jellyfishtechnologies/Desktop/Vivek/My Game Project/Flyer/Flyer/HomePageScene.mm:91:43: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CCScene *' with an lvalue of type 'SettingScene *'
```

I dont understand what the exact problem!!!

Comment: Show the definition of `SettingScene`.

Comment: Did you implement the scene method in SettingScene class??

Comment: make sure that your SettingScene is subclass of CCScene.

Comment: Probably the overridden static method node returns a CCScene* instead of a SettingScene* (or better ad id).

Comment: thanks @trojanfoe I got it.
Actually I made CCNode as super class of settingScene instead of CCScene. I thought it will work but perhaps I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your SETTINGS class is not a subclass of CCScene or it isn't returning a CCScene Object. Please verify this.